# What is the internal format of UIImage?

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory, uiimage, ipod

---

for ipad

e.g. 
for pixel size 10x10 image, how much memory is used?

provide some other contribution:
   usually for a normal iPad, it start with app-usable memory of 190-200mb
   this number decrease if background process / other apps is running

many thanks!~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 x 10 x 4 = 400bytes for that image, so it's 4 bytes per pixel. (GRBA).

Also it is normal for background app to take some memory. iOS will free memory if needed by any app.